# How to remove a set of characters from a user inputted float - Python

Tags: python

I just started picking up python and I want to know how to do what I said in the title. The only background in programming I have is a semester long C++ class that I had in high school that I got a C in and forgot almost everything from. Here's my code:

```
while True:
try:
    height_m = float(input("Enter your height in meters: "))
except ValueError:
    print ("Please enter a number without any other characters.")
    continue
else:break
while True:
try:
    weight_kg = float(input("Enter your weight in kilograms: "))
except ValueError:
    print ("Please enter a number without any other characters.")
    continue
else:break
bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
print ("Your bmi is",(bmi),".")
if bmi < 18.5:
    print ("You are underweight.")
elif 18.5 <= bmi <=24.9:
    print ("You are of normal weight.")
elif 25 <= bmi <= 29.9:
    print ("You are overweight.")
else:
    print ("You are obese.")
```

As you can see, it's just a basic BMI calculator. However, what I wanted to do was make it so that if someone were to input "1.8 m", "1.8 meters" or "1.8 ms" and the equivalent for kilograms, the program would remove the extra input and process it as if they hadn't added that. Also, any extra tips you have for me would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the third line with this:

```
height_m = float(''.join([e for e in input("Enter your height in meters: ") if not e.isalpha()]))
```

It works by removing all alphabets before converting to float.

Comment: Thanks you! For future reference, what's this called so I can look it up later to better understand how it works?

Comment: `[e for e in input("Enter your height in meters: ") if not e.isalpha()]` is called a list comprehension - basically a mini for loop. `"".join(<list>)` will join the elements of a list into a string.

Comment: @MemeSoap its list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

In general, this works

```
Height_List = []
Height  = input("What is your height")
for i  in Height:
    if i in "1234567890.":
        Height_List.append(i)
Actual_Height = float("".join(Height_List))
```

Comment: Actual_Height should be float("".join(Height_List). I wrote int by mistake. For some reason i couldn't edit. It's all right now thanks to ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000.